# Can a drone make a heroic contribution?

Tags: style

Is the style of this sentence acceptable to Chinese ears? What is heroic about a drone?

无论是在生活还是救援等工作中，无人机都立下汗马功劳。

Can a drone 'make a heroic contribution'??

Or 汗马功劳 here just means:工作中的贡献, basically just 'contributions, achievements'?

Maybe she is just using flowery language?? I should forget the 'war hero exploits' implication?

Comment: "What is heroic about a drone?" - Nothing; "Or 汗马功劳 here just means:工作中的贡献, basically just 'contributions, achievements'?" - Yes

Comment: 汗马 (sweating and running around on horseback)  refers to 'laborious task'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 无论是在生活还是救援等工作中，无人机都立下汗马功劳。

it’s very bad, the assumption & consideration behind the sentence.

even if we think of personification (擬人), treat a drone as a human being. then,

- do we glorify a train in daily transportation?
- a rocket in space mission?
- a pen / typewriter in award-winning novel writing?

these’re tools. the quoted sentence only praises the drone, ignoring the factor-workers who made them, the operators to control on site.

it’s these people who make contributions & achievements.

stop of rant :)

Comment: Thank you! Drone, for me, has very bad connotations. You know the CIA joke perhaps: What is the difference between a primary school and a terrorist training camp?? Don't ask me, I just fly the drone!

Comment: haha, garbage in, garbage out, do your best to avoid this type of text 

Comment: People  do glorify WWII weapons. Mostly tanks,  airplanes and famous warships

Answer (score 2):

> 无论是在生活还是救援等工作中，无人机都立下汗马功劳。

The sentence isn't unusual.  It's quite natural to my ear. It's just a way saying drones are very useful with respect to daily life or rescue operations.  You can take it as an expression, personification, or whatever.  This kind of expression is used in kinds of medias.